# NestedScrollView content is smaller than screen height

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, android-nestedscrollview

I know that this question is often ask but i don't find the way to do properly in my case.

As you can see in my xml file, i'm using CoordinatorLayout, NestedScrollView and AppBarLayout. When the nestedScrollview content is smaller than the screen height, it let blank extra space for nothing.

How can i remove this blank extra space?

Thanks for all

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#f000f0"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Hello World!" />

                <!-- more content but not enought to fill screen -->

            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="200dp"
                        android:background="#ff0000">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/main_linearlayout_title"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                            android:text="PSEUDO"
                            android:textColor="#ffffff"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />
                    </LinearLayout>


                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/main_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark">

<!-- some content (title) -->
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Edit 1** :

- Withou Scroll

[image]

- With NestedScrollView height wrap_content

[image]

- With NestedScrollView height match_parent (so it's the same probleme, instead to have blank space, it's pink but it rest a extra useless space)

[image]

So to be clear i want nothing under the last "Hello World" and don't scroll more than necessary.

Comment: what do you want to achieve?

Comment: @MarkBuikema I don't want this extra space and finish the view at the end of hello worlds

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve. What do you want the empty space to be used for?

Comment: @MarkBuikema i don't want to can scroll more than my content and don't see this empty space.

Answer (score 0):

Set the height of your `NestedScrollView` to `match_parent`.

Answer (score -1):

Set your *NestedScrollView*'s height to *match_parent*. Set your *LinearLayout*'s height to *match_parent*. Modify your *TextView* as

```
 <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="hello world"/>
```

Assign each *TextView* a height of 0dp and weight of 1.*layout_weight* specifies how much of the extra space in the layout to be allocated to the View.What this does is expand your *TextView*s equally into the remaining space(In this case it happens to be the complete screen).
[Explanation in the official developers doc.](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear)

Comment: I'ts the same as nested scrollview height match_parent.. I don't want to scroll more than necessary

Comment: if you don't want that then use scrollview height as wrap_content

Comment: So it's my original problem

Comment: you say you don't want that blank extra space but doesn't my solution fill up your screen and remove all blank space?

Comment: i said i don't want this extra space at all, blank or not it's the same, this is an useless space and scroll for users